# How do I set a Tag attribute to a typeof(Page) in XAML for UWP application?

Tags: uwp-xaml

How do I set a Tag attribute (which is type System.Object) to the type of a Page in XAML for a UWP application?

In particular I am declaring a NavigationViewItem in XAML, and I would like to set it's Tag to the type of a Page, e.g.

```
<NavigationViewItem Icon="Home" Content="Home" Tag=views:HomePage />
```

In C# I would code something like this `navItem.Tag = typeof(HomePage)`.

Note that I am not trying to set the Tag to an instance of the page but rather the Type of a page.
If I quote the `views:HomeView` part, it gets stored as a string. I declared the views namespace previously:

```
xmlns:views="using:MyApp.Views"
```

How can I assign an attribute a value for typeof(Page) in XAML? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derive a class from NavigationViewItem, add a Tag property of type Type and use the new keyword to hide the inherited Tag property of type object.

```
public class NavigationViewItemEx : NavigationViewItem
{
   public new Type Tag { get; set; }
}
```

You'll need to qualify the types in XAML. At the top with other namespaces for the Page
    `xmlns:local="using:App1"`
Then in the page content itself use the following:

```
<NavigationView SelectionChanged="NavigationView_OnSelectionChanged">
  <NavigationView.MenuItems>
     <local:NavigationViewItemEx Icon="Home" Content="Home" TargetPageType="local:MainPage" />
      ...
</NavigationView>
```

Processing the OnSelectionChanged event is as usual, but cast the SelectedItem to your new class rather than NavigationViewItem.

```
private void NavigationView_OnSelectionChanged(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewSelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
   NavigationViewItemEx selectedItem = args.SelectedItem as NavigationViewItemEx;
   Type targetPageType = selectedItem?.Tag;
   //null checking, etc. here
   yourFrame.Navigate(targetPageType);
   ...
```

This answers the question, but some people are uncomfortable with hiding an inherited property, so using a different property (e.g. `TargetPageType`) instead of Tag may be more palatable.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to assign the Tag with a Page object, but you can try to using [data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-quickstart) to bind a Page object to your [`NavigationViewItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationviewitem).

Page.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <NavigationView Name="Nav" ItemInvoked="Nav_ItemInvoked">
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Home" Content="Home" Tag="{x:Bind PageCollection[0]}"/>
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>
    </NavigationView>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    PageCollection = new ObservableCollection<Page>();
    //Add page instances
    BlankPage1 blankPage1 = new BlankPage1();
    PageCollection.Add(blankPage1);
}

public ObservableCollection<Page> PageCollection { get; set; }

private void Nav_ItemInvoked(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
{
    var item = sender.MenuItems[0] as NavigationViewItem;
    Debug.WriteLine(item.Tag.GetType());
}
```

---Update---

If you want to set the tag to a `Type`, you can put the type in a collection, then bind the Type item to the Tag. So the code behind would look like this:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    PageCollection = new ObservableCollection<Type>();
    //Add page type so that you can bind and navigate to the tag page.
    PageCollection.Add(typeof(BlankPage1));
}

public ObservableCollection<Type> PageCollection { get; set; }

private void Nav_ItemInvoked(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
{
    var item = sender.MenuItems[0] as NavigationViewItem;
    Debug.WriteLine(item.Tag.GetType());
    Frame.Navigate((Type)item.Tag);
}
```

---Update 2---

If you don't want to use the data binding with the code behind, what I can consider is to use a resource in your page to add a object then you can use your tag to refer it.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:BlankPage1 x:Key="Page1" />
</Page.Resources>
<NavigationView ItemInvoked="Nav_ItemInvoked">
    <NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <NavigationViewItem Icon="Home" Content="Home" Tag="{StaticResource Page1}" />
    </NavigationView.MenuItems>
</NavigationView>
```

Then you can Navigate to the page by the tag,

```
Frame.Navigate(navItem.Tag.GetType());
```

Comment: I was not clear. I don't want to set Tag to an instance of a page, but rather the type of a page. Navigation would then be possible with Frame.Navigate(navItem.Tag). All examples I've seen require a mapping of string tags to types of pages to navigate to, and I would like to avoid the messy mappings.

Comment: @CoderBrian I have add the Update part in my answer, you can create a Collection which include Type type item so that you can use Tag to bind and navigate to the page.

Comment: It seems there should be a way in XAML alone (i.e. without code behind or biding) to reference the `Type` of a `Page`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Okay, I have add the **Update 2** part for your requirement to avoid using code behind or binding.